# Run Azure Databricks Notebook from Apache Nifi

Tags: etl, apache-nifi, azure-databricks

I am new to apache Nifi, is there any way to run Azure Databricks notebook from Nifi?
Or is to be done by different tool?

Answer (score 0):

You can run Azure databricks notebook from Apache Nifi.
To Connect Databricks Data in Apache NiFi

1. Download the CData JDBC Driver for Databricks installer, unzip the package, and run the JAR file to install the driver.
2. Copy the CData JDBC Driver JAR file (and license file if it exists), `cdata.jdbc.databricks.jar` (and cdata.jdbc.databricks.lic), to the Apache NiFi lib subfolder, for example, `C:\nifi-1.3.0-bin\nifi-1.3.0\lib`.

On Windows, the default location for the CData JDBC Driver is `C:\Program Files\CData\CData` JDBC Driver for Databricks.

3. Start Apache NiFi. For example:

   ```
   cd C:\nifi-1.3.0-bin\nifi-1.3.0\bin
   run-nifi.bat
   ```
4. Lastly Navigate to the Apache NiFi UI in your web browser: typically http://localhost:8080/nifi

You can refer this article( https://www.cdata.com/kb/tech/databricks-jdbc-apache-nifi.rst  ) for more information